# Nodemailer + Handlebars encrypt href link to forward

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I have a project using NodeMailer + Handlebars to send and tracking email, now i want to change every href link to project url before forward to destination link.

Example:

Origin mail:

```
<a href='http://google.com'>Click here </a> to forwad
```

Will be change to:

```
<a href='http://localhost:8080/track?fw=http://google.com.vn'>Click here </a> to forwad
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can replace all URL by yourself with:

```
var originMail = '<a href='http://google.com'>Click here </a> to forwad';
var newMail = originMail.replace('://', '://localhost:8000/track?fw=');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: See my Edit. Maybe you can just replace "://" ? It will works for http and https

Comment: Hi, it not replace all. Only replace first match.